# How can I qualify a lead in Dynamics 365 when Dynamics 365 is embedded in Microsoft Teams App?

Tags: dynamics-crm, office365, microsoft-teams, dynamics-365, office365-apps

When we login to Office 365 and use our Dynamics 365 Web App we can easily qualify a lead by clicking the "Qualify" link.

We use Microsoft Teams (MacOS app) and have embedded the Dynamics 365 App. However, we are unable to qualify a lead due to the Dynamics 365 command bar not being rendered.

[image: Dynamics 365 Web Version]

[image: Dynamics 365 MS Teams Version (MacOS)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am also experiencing the same behavior when I use the embedded Dynamics App in MS Teams. Reason is the embedded url has `cmdbar=false` in it.

[image]

> [image]

When I change the url querystring in popped out url as `cmdbar=true`, I see the command bar/ribbon buttons.

> [image]

Not sure about this, it could be a bug & a MS ticket can confirm this.

Alternately If you use the tab component, it works nicely.

[image]

> [image]

Comment: Tab idea works well. I’ve raised a UserVoice bug here if anyone thinks it should be voted up... https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/908686-bug-reports/suggestions/39268675-dynamics-365